# Python Multiprocessing Pool.map() on Mac runs processes serially instead of in parallel

Tags: python, macos, multiprocessing

I have been writing a script to sort and filter a large data set and split the work over multiple CPU cores (by using multiple processes) however, Python seems to start each process one at a time running them serially instead of in parallel.

I have stripped the code right back so that it is essentially doing nothing useful (it generates a list of random numbers and simply deletes them all), and the problem persists. Is this a problem with Python on Mac?

I'm running Python 3.7.1 on OS X 10.13.6.

This is the full code:

```py
import math
import multiprocessing
import os
import random
import sys
import timeit


def delete_all(passed_nums):

    print("Started process: {}, {}".format(multiprocessing.current_process(), os.getpid()))
    while (len(passed_nums) > 0):
        passed_nums.remove(passed_nums[0])
    print("Finished process: {}, {}".format(multiprocessing.current_process(), os.getpid()))

    return passed_nums


def chunksl(l, n):

    i = [l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
    return i


def main():

    rnd_nums = random.sample(range(1, 1000000), 500000)
    num_processes = 1
    Pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_processes)

    list_chunk_size_per_core = int(math.ceil(len(rnd_nums)/float(num_processes)))

    unsorted_sub_lists = list(chunksl(rnd_nums, list_chunk_size_per_core))

    print("Number of CPUs:  {}".format(num_processes))
    print("Chunk size per CPU: {}".format(list_chunk_size_per_core))
    print("Number of chunks: {}".format(len(unsorted_sub_lists)))

    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    sorted_sub_lists = Pool.map(delete_all, unsorted_sub_lists, list_chunk_size_per_core)
    end_time = timeit.default_timer()
    print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))

    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

This is the output with `num_processes = 1`:

```
Number of CPUs:  1
Chunk size per CPU: 500000
Number of chunks: 1
Started process: <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>, 1617
Finished process: <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>, 1617
Duration: 23.922029328999997
```

This is the output with `num_processes = 2`:

```
Number of CPUs:  2
Chunk size per CPU: 250000
Number of chunks: 2
Started process: <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>, 1630
Finished process: <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>, 1630
Started process: <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>, 1630
Finished process: <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>, 1630
Duration: 11.938197925
```

Finally, this is the output with `num_processes = 1` but reducing the size of the list to 250,000 entries instead of 500,000:

```
Number of CPUs:  1
Chunk size per CPU: 250000
Number of chunks: 1
Started process: <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>, 1639
Finished process: <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>, 1639
Duration: 5.904828338
```

It can be seen that when `num_processes = 2` the script runs faster, but not because it is running processes in parallel, but because deleting all entries in two 250k item lists is quicker than deleting all entries in one 500k item list (the output from when `num_processes = 2` is twice the duration of the last run when `num_processes = 1` but the list size is reduced to 250k entries, which is also roughly one quarte of the time for the first run).

My understanding is that when starting a new process, using `Pool.map()` each process receives a full copy of its chunk of the list `unsorted_sub_lists`, which means that multiple processes aren't blocking trying to access the original `unsorted_sub_lists` list simultaneously. Python isn't passing by reference to new process. I can print the list `unsorted_sub_lists` at the end of the script and the original contents are still there so I assume my understanding is correct?

Comment: "It can be seen that when num_processes = 2 the script runs faster, but not because it is running processes in parallel, but because deleting all entries in two 250k item lists is quicker than deleting all entries in one 500k item " Is it? Why do you say so?

Comment: 1) the task is not growing linearly with the length of the list, you can try with one process and 1-2-3-4-5(00k) items 2) I think `chunksize` for the `Pool.map()` call should be 1 as `unsorted_sub_lists` consists of `num_processes` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `n` processes, the variable `unsorted_sub_lists` has `n` elements. So when you pass `chunksize=list_chunk_size_per_core` where `list_chunk_size_per_core` is 250k, you're chunking a list of length 2 into max length 250k chunks, essentially duplicating the work on each process. Try either fixing your `unsorted_sub_lists` to be length 500k, or just remove the `chunksize` parameter in the `Pool.map` call

Comment: Ah OK, I read the documentation but I have misinterpreted it. From (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) `This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive integer.` - it doesn't explain that it will by default chop the iterator into the number of CPUs in the pool. The result I wanted is achieved by removing the chunksize argument.

Comment: What's not clear from the documentation is that having no `chunksize` argument when I have 2 CPUs in the pool, and setting `chunksize` to 2 when I have 2 CPUs in the pool, produces two different behaviours. I RTFM as `you can specificy how large a chunk you want to be given to each CPU (i.e. you could distribute the work unevenly if you really wanted to)` but that is not the case.